# Visual Studio c# Dynamic control is twice the size as the one made in designer

Tags: c#

I made a panel in vs 2017 community edition and set the size property to 600, 100.
I then added a panel dynamically with the code:

```
panel.Size = new Size(600, 100);
```

The dynamic panel was 50% bigger when run(900, 150).
I tested a textbox and got the same results so I assume it is the same for all controls. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Probably due to [DPI scaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681(v=vs.85).aspx).  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the size does not change try:

```
        panel.MinimumSize = new Size(600,100);
        panel.MaximumSize = new Size(600, 100);
```